# Joining multiple tables multiple ways

Tags: python, sql, join, pyspark, amazon-athena

I have 5 tables like below:
Table A

| rank. | input. |
| --- | --- |
| 0. | aa |
| 1. | bb |
| 2 | cc |
| 3 | dd ​ |

Table B

| rank. | input. |
| --- | --- |
| 0. | aa |
| 3 | cc |
| 4 | dd |
| 5 | ee ​ |

Table C

| rank. | input. |
| --- | --- |
| 0. | aa |
| 5 | ee |
| 6 | ff |
| 7 | gg ​ |

Table D

| rank. | input. |
| --- | --- |
| 0. | aa |
| 2 | bb |
| 6 | ff |
| 7 | gg ​ |

I need the output to be like below:

Final table

| rank. | input. |
| --- | --- |
| 0. | aa |
| 2 | bb |
| 3 | cc |
| 5 | ee ​ |
| 6 | ff |
| 7 | gg ​ |

If i just cross join all the tables depending on the biggest table, i get the below output :

| rank. | input. |
| --- | --- |
| 0. | aa |

Is there a way to get the output i want without having to do multiple joins across AB,BC,CD,BD etc..

Please let me know. I can either use SQL or Pyspark to do this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Sample table data is great, but you should also _specify_ the expected result. And also show us your current query attempt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can union all the tables, group by input and get the maximum of the rank:

```
select max(`rank`) as `rank`, input
from (
    select * from tableA
    union all
    select * from tableB
    union all
    select * from tableC
    union all
    select * from tableD
) t
group by input
```

In Pyspark it would be

```
from functools import reduce

df = reduce(lambda a, b: a.unionAll(b), [tableA,tableB,tableC,tableD])
result = df.groupBy('input').agg(F.max('rank').alias('rank'))
```